# Conditional Formatting using Index/Match

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am working on a workbook that has a number of worksheets, and I am trying to apply conditional formatting for a cell one sheet based on the value of a cell in another. I noticed the following phenomenon, for which I don't have a good explanation:

In one sheet, I have an array of random numbers between 0 and 1 whose rows correspond to names (or numbers), and whose column corresponds to dates. The names and numbers are the first column and row of the spreadsheet, respectively. In another sheet, I have a similar array, but the dates and names ordered differently and the cells are empty.

Now, when I use the following formula in a cell in the second sheet:

```
INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$K$11,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$11,0),MATCH(B$1,Sheet1!$B$1:$K$1,0))>0.5
```

to determine whether the number corresponding to that particular name and date is greater than .5, excel returns the proper `TRUE/FALSE` value. However, when I use the same formula for conditional formatting, such as changing the fill of the cell in question in sheet2 based on the `TRUE/FALSE` value of the above formula, the formatting is not applied.

Why is this? There is probably a simple answer to this question, but I have searched and I couldn't figure it out. I hope the question is clear, but if not, I'll try to edit it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When using a formula in a CF rule it's important to select the cells starting at the top-left and dragging down and right: this is because it matters where the ActiveCell is relative to the area to be formatted.  Selecting a range by dragging up and to the left from the bottom-right produces a totally different result when you apply a CF formula

Comment: I'm aware of that, but the formatting isn't being applied even when I choose a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly why Excel does what might only be fully answerable by Microsoft.

Guessing slightly what you layout is, your formula will work (if the range starts at B2) provided you replace the ranges in your formula with appropriate Named Ranges of Workbook scope.